# Bizarre php bug - adding junk code stops script from dying?

Tags: php, nginx

I have a php script that returns a 502 error, "upstream prematurely closed FastCGI stdout while reading response header". I tracked down the last point in my code that will return before the script dies. It's just before a function returns a variable.

Weirdly, if right before the return I put this code, the script completes all the way to the end:

if($adsfjahdflkjhdfklajhsdf == "yo") die();

Why would adding this line of code make any difference between a script finishing or not?

Comment: It looks like you are not using curly braces `{}` when writing PHP constructs; I would bet that there is a flaw, or several, in the flow of your code.

Comment: Thanks! So maybe I'm missing a bracket somewhere? Would it necessarily be within the function this line went in, or could it be anywhere in all my code (all classes, etc)?

Comment: More info: when the same php page is fed a different ID (this script displays data, when it displays different data), the page has no error. If it's a flow error, why would it error only on certain kinds of data? Mysql calls are fine, it doesn't appear to be that the data is corrupt.

Comment: I honestly do not know and nobody on this site can really guide you in the right direction without seeing all of your code. If your code is omitting curly braces consistently then the chance of having an issue or uncaught logic are exponentiated. As-is, your question does not have a definite answer.

Comment: Gotcha. Well, knowing it's a bad idea to leave out curly braces is a pointer, thank you! I'll start with that.